# Select query an int or nvarchar value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a search function that is able to search by condition, platenumber and maximum volume using a select statement:

```
select Condition, PlateNumber, MaximumVolumeLoad 
from [Truck Table] 
where Condition=@id OR PlateNumber=@id OR MaximumVolumeLoad>=@id
```

However, the problem is My MaximumVolumeLoad column is set into int and whenever I search for the condition, I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'good' to data type int.

Is there any way where I can search for them at the same time without having to create another query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea, but you can do it by converting the value to a number:

```
select Condition, PlateNumber, MaximumVolumeLoad
from [Truck Table] tt
where Condition = @id or
      PlateNumber = @id or
      MaximumVolumeLoad >= try_convert(int, @id);
```

Note that if the value is not a valid integer, this will return `NULL`, so it will never match `MaximumVolumeLoad`.  Presumably, this is the correct behavior.

Comment: getting this error: "Try_Convert" is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: @D.Trump123 - that's because it comes in SQL Server 2012 and you seem to have an older version. What is your version of SQL Server, is it at least 2008?

Comment: I have SQL server 2014

Comment: Your database compatibility level seems to be set lower, though. Try running the following: ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120; . This will set your database to compatibility level of SQL Server 2014.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad we could help.

Answer (score 0):

May be an alternative to what has been suggested by Gordon is to convert the column to varchar before the compare. This should behave in the same way.

```
select Condition, PlateNumber, MaximumVolumeLoad
from [Truck Table] tt
where Condition = @id or
  PlateNumber = @id or
  cast(MaximumVolumeLoad as varchar(10)) >=  @id;
```

Note: Forgot to add that it assumes that you will have alphabets in the @id. Based on ASCII character set numbers come before alphabets. So this should work as expected if it is any string that is entered.
But is you check for '2' >= '+' the results could go wrong. (if @id has a value of a '+')